# Zoom with right click

Tags: autohotkey

Is there any way to zoom in using autohotkey on a region of the screen, then display that region fullscreen?
I.e(pseudo code);

```
x = 300 
y = 300
x_region = 400
y_region = 200
surface_zoomed = surface.cropped(x,y,x_region,y_region)
surface_zoomed.transform(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
surface_zoomed.blit()
```

Where most of these aren't actual methods or classes, are there plugins to make this functional?
Is there a way to implement something like this into AHK using right click?

Comment: you can start here https://the-automator.com/screen-clipping/

Comment: Quick search found something [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=67467)